# Compiler is skipping incompatible library when using OpenCV in QT

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm trying to use OpenCV in QT, it seems that the library is not linked. I've checked the version of opencv_core455d.lib, it is a 32 bit library, and my QT application is in 64 bit mode. Is it the problem and should I compile OpenCV in 64 bit mode?

.pro file(part):

```
LIBS += -L"D:\\env\\opencv\\build\\lib\\Debug" -lopencv_core455d
INCLUDEPATH += D:\\env\\opencv\\build\\include
```

main.cpp(full):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    cv::Mat mat;
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

compiler output:

```
:-1: error: skipping incompatible D:\env\opencv\build\lib\Debug/opencv_core455d.lib when searching for -lopencv_core455d
:-1: error: skipping incompatible D:\env\opencv\build\lib\Debug/opencv_core455d.lib when searching for -lopencv_core455d
:-1: error: skipping incompatible D:\env\opencv\build\lib\Debug\opencv_core455d.lib when searching for -lopencv_core455d
:-1: error: cannot find -lopencv_core455d
:-1: error: skipping incompatible D:\env\opencv\build\lib\Debug/opencv_core455d.lib when searching for -lopencv_core455d
:-1: error: collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
:-1: error: [Makefile.Debug:72: debug/testopencv5.exe] Error 1
```

Comment: Yes, you can't link together 32 bit and 64 bit code

Comment: why is it 32-bit though? you must have gone to some *extra trouble* to find 32-bit libraries of OpenCV